# Why does my LM7805CV output voltage drop at loads <= 150 mA?

Tags: lm78xx

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/200850/15390) the LM7805 has no minimum load. The [data sheet](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/81/69/816934/lm7806a.pdf) also indicates that the output voltage should remain between 4.8 and 5.2 V for output currents of between 5 mA and 1 A.

I have a LM7805CA from an unknown manufacturer (I don't recognize the logo, which is an upward-pointing triangle to the left of a downward facing triangle enclosed by lines on all but the bottom side), but the additional markings appear to be "GOOKJ V6" and "MAR 918." (Unfortunately the printing on it is such that it's difficult to read and near-impossible to photograph.)

I've got the output hooked up to a constant-current variable load and the input is around 9 V (I see similar behaviour throughout a 7 V to 12 V input range) from a bench power supply, like so:

[image: LM7805-test]

The LM7805 is underneath the red alligator clip (you can just see the edge peeking out the top) and test clips you see there lead to my multimeter; I'm taking all voltage readings from that since it's more accurate than the load's display. (The actual output voltage in the piacture is 4.96 V.)

As you can see in the image, with about 170 mA of load the output voltage is within spec. As I increase the load to 200 mA the output voltage increases to around 5.02 V and stays there even up past 500 mA.

However, when I reduce the load to around 120 mA the voltage drops to 4.84 V (still within spec, but barely) and at 80 mA the output voltage drops to 4.72 V. The load won't reliably sink much less than this (I have seen 4.66 V at around 60 mA), but earlier, playing with just an LED and 330 Ω resistor in series between the output and ground (on a breadboard), I saw the output voltage drop even further, to around 4 V.

So what's going on here? Is this device really going out of spec, or is it something to do with the way I'm measuring things?

Comment: Have you followed the designs in the datasheet for the LM7805?

Comment: "If it is going out of spec, is that just expected for random no-name parts from AliExpress?" You can have absolutely no expectations whatsoever from Ali. This is a standard component, highly available around the world. Just buy one from a well-known silicon vendor. But of course it's "cheaper" to buy unknown crap and trouble-shoot for hours than to pay $1 for a proper component, right?

Comment: @Lundin I'd love to pay $1 for a proper component. The problem is, by the time it gets to my door from Mouser or similar vendors that $1 component has turned into a $20 component.

Comment: Still, that's probably the sane way to go. Get one from ON Semi, TI, ST etc - some well-known manufacturer.

Comment: If you **are** going to buy components that are, as you said "random, no-name parts", then you just have to live with what you get. It isn't reasonable to come here and expect a good answer when your parts could be counterfeit or damaged or factory rejects. We get weary reading questions like this, sorry.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ok, so if I'm reading your response right in the context of the question: 1) "Am I measuring this right" questions are not welcome here; you should already know you are, and 2) In the real world of hardware design parts always meet their specs and so it is not necessary to have any debugging skills for dealing with situations in which parts don't meet their specs.

Comment: Why did you remove the part about your component being sourced from AliExpress from your question? It seems relevant to me. Are you hoping omitting that information will change our answers?

Comment: And to explain Elliot's remark; we get this a lot. Someone buys parts from AliExpress / DealExtreme / Ebay / whathaveyou, tries something with them, and something doesn't work as expected. They ask a question here, people put in effort trying to debug the problem. Turns out some cheaply obtained part is junk. Mildly amusing the first time, less so the next thousand times. Because this happens frequently, people are less inclined to help when there's lottery parts involved, and instead they just tell you to buy proper parts first. I can't blame them.

Comment: You **can** ask how to properly make measurements, but that's not what you asked. You asked "Is this device really going out of spec, or..." Since you have no spec there is no way to answer this part of the question, and we would only proceed to the second part of your question if the answer to the first part was clearly "no". To answer the second part we would need to know the specifications for your active load and for your meter. We would need to see a schematic of the connections...did you add any capacitors to prevent oscillation?

Comment: I agree with the comments above. Usually you can tell by whether or not the supplier has datasheets. "No datasheet? No sale!" But back to the problem: your meter will give an average current reading. Is your load pulsed or PWM? If so it may be overloading the supply but you can't see it. Edit your question to give load details.

Comment: @Transistor I have no further details on the first load mentioned, but I felt I had given all the details for the second load; is there something I'm missing there?

Answer (score 1):

Measuring with an LED and 330 Ω resistor is okay. So if you did that measurement correctly and it only provides 4V then it doesn't meet the spec in the data sheet you linked. (Whether that's the spec for that actual part is unknown since the manufacturer is unknown.)

When measuring with that variable load device, you may need capacitors depending on what exactly the load is doing.