# Problem with building -12/12 V power supply and AC/AC converter

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, ac-dc

At the beginning I wanted to point out that I don't know much about electronics and I'm just starting my adventure with it.

I recently bought an AC/AC 12 V power supply and to my surprise, it showed 15 V AC after measuring the output voltage. I wrote to the seller and he replied that it is normal if the device works without load.

I built a simple converter that would allow me to get 12 V DC from this power supply, but after measuring the output voltage, I got about 20 V DC. Is the problem with the converter schematic or with the power supply?

[image: schematic]

I measured 19 V after the first capacitor and the power supply still produces 15 V AC. I wonder what should I do in this situation. Should I buy a new power supply or replace the capacitors or something else?

Comment: Welcome! That’s normal and asked about several times before. If your end goal is +-12 V DC, why not just buy suck a power supply in the first place? If not, you need two voltage regulator, one positive and one negative.

Comment: "I got about 20 V DC [output] voltage" Are you sure you got the regulator ICs connected correctly? Note that the 7812 and 7912 have different pinouts.

Comment: You show a single AC lead. Where is the other end of your transformer connected? Are you sure?

Comment: where does that 20v appear? between -12 and 12 or between 12 and gnd?

Comment: is the transformer center-tapped? Everything you describe sounds about right, and you should be a tweak or two away from have a clean 12/-12v dual DC supply.

Comment: The comments and links in this answer may be useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/484766/why-does-my-lm7805cv-output-voltage-drop-at-loads-150-ma. This answer is also interesting: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/200850/194393

Comment: How much current you need from regulators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AC voltage is normally stated as an RMS (Root Mean Square - a "sort of" average value).

If you rectify an AC voltage with a diode and capacitor, the resulting DC voltage will be about 1.4 times the AC RMS voltage minus the voltage drop across the diode, so rectifying 12 VAC should give about 16 VDC.

Cheap "wall wart" transformers are often fairly lossy.  They will produce somewhat above their advertised voltage with no load, and reduce the voltage to the advertised value when loaded to near their specified maximum output current.

Comment: so you think that I should buy a new transformer?

Comment: @pggu11: No.   Your results are what I would expect.  But regulated 12 VDC supplies should be readily avaialble, if that is what you want.

Comment: so what should I do to make this work. My problem is that stock 12VDC would be far too noisy for my use and ones with minimum noise would be too expensive in my opinion.

Comment: Why would they be too noisy, or more expensive?

Comment: Im using it as a modular synthesizer (musical instrument) power supply and I can't afford any unwanted noise in resulting sound. Also I just read it online that they are too noisy. On most sites about diy synth building they recommend circuits similar to this one that Im using. Usually modular synthesizer psu's cost more than 60$ so I dont think that it's worth if you can build one for less than half of that

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and test it yourself with any two cheapo 12 V supplies wired in series first.

Comment: Have a look at the schematics of old skool synths like the prophet 5 , minimoog and juno6.

Comment: @PeterBennett I needed a low-noise, low current  ±12V supply and ended up building something very similar to this but with less capacitance

Answer (score 4):

"I wonder if the problem is with the converter schematic or with the power supply?"

My money is on the schematic. 7812/7912 regulators aren't actually specified at no load. Try connecting a 1k resistor (1/2 watt or better) from each output to ground.

Comment: "7812/7912 regulators aren't actually specified at no load" A good point. All the 78xx/79xx series are specified for a minimum load of 5 mA. (If all else fails read the datasheet.)

Comment: But lets not forget that the minimum load is provided by its own internal voltage divider, so, there is no minimum *external* load. @GrahamNye As a comparison with the same era, the LM317, which is a floating regulator, has an explicit minimum load.

Comment: The data sheet only specifies output voltage for output currents over 5 mA.

Comment: Yes. And most parameters are only specified for 500mA.

Answer (score 4):

Your circuit looks fine. You shouldn't get 20V output even at no load. You likely have something mis-wired.

Certainly if the diode is backwards that would account for it. If you're not sure it's correct remove it and re-check the voltages (it's not required for the circuit).

Another likely culprit is getting the pinout of the regulator(s) wrong. The pinouts are different for the 78xx and 79xx, the tab being ground for the 78xx but the negative input for the 79xx (so they can't be attached to the same heat sink).

And of course, your AC input should attach to the diode junction (as shown in schematic) and ground (assumed, but not shown in schematic).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you actually measuring an AC voltage here? If you are using a basic multimeter, it may be misleading you.

The simplest way to measure AC is to feed the AC voltage through a precision rectifier, measure the resulting DC, and apply a correction factor to convert to the RMS voltage of the original AC.

So if you connect a multimeter set to AC volts to a DC supply, it will give a reading that is wrong.